# Save Image base 64 AngularJS Spring-Batch

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-batch, blob

I need to allow the user to choose a image from his pc, then this image should be save in the database in a blob column.
I have this code for select image:

```
<input type="file" id="fileSelector1" class="form-control" name="schemeupload" accept="image/jpeg" file-model="vm.schemeApply.documents[0]"/>
```

Then I have to cast the image to base64 for sending to the back(java) and then in the back part insert the base64 string into de blob column? or I have to do in other way? is first time I have to save image.

I know that is not efficient to save image as that but I have to do in that way.

EDIT:
I use now this:

```
<input type="file" id="fileSelector1" class="form-control" name="schemeupload" ng-model="img_icon" file-model as-file accept="image/jpeg" ng-change="onFileSelected(this)" />
```

But I don´t know how to get the img for getting base64 string

Answer (score 1):

This is a plain JavaScript solution without [angularjs-file-model](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-file-model) demonstrating how to convert a selected file to BASE64. You can take this as a starting point:

```js
function onFileSelected(input) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener('load', event => {
        const dataURL = event.target.result;
        
        // Cut away "data:image/png;base64,"
        const base64 = dataURL.substring(dataURL.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
        console.log(base64);
    });

    reader.addEventListener('error', () => {
        // Error handling code
    })
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileSelector1" class="form-control" name="schemeupload" accept="image/jpeg" onchange="onFileSelected(this)">
```

`angularjs-file-model` should project the file object into your model when using `file-model` together with `as-file`. You might be able to use it here instead of `input.files[0]`.

Comment: I¨m getting this error :majusebetter:(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: onFileSelected is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):1)

Comment: Yes, this is a plain JavaScript solution. For AngularJS you need to use some directive. As you are using `angularjs-file-model` your HTML has to look like this: `<input type="file" ng-model="files" file-model as-file ng-change="onFileSelected()">`. Just remove the `input` parameter from `onFileSelected()` and use the `files` property of your model within the function instead of `input.files`.

Comment: thanks is first time I have to do that so is something new... going to try

Comment: Great, now is working, when I select the image it enters the method, for the input parameter which variable should I use? I have the ng-model a path like that: C\fakepath\name.jpeg and if i put as parameter in the html: onFileSelected(this) doesn´t have target attribute, any idea?

Comment: Did you also use `as-file` in your markup? According to the documentation it should bind the File object to your model. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-file-model

Comment: <input type="file" id="fileSelector1" class="form-control" name="schemeupload" ng-model="img_icon"  file-model as-file  accept="image/jpeg" ng-change="onFileSelected(this)" /> but the ng-model variable still c\fakepath\name.jpeg

Comment: solved in a easier way, without using any external , the file I take when i select the picture, i pass through a reader and it takes base64